# How to debug macros with Visual Studio Debugger

Tags: c, visual-studio-2022

How to debug macros defined in the header files? How to give the debugger this information?
In my project, there is a big Array containing a lot of variables. There are a lot of macros defined in "Typedef.h", for example:

```cpp
#define var1 x[0]
#define var2 x[1]
```

When debugging, I always have to know the Index of the Variable.
Is it possible to use the Names "var1", "var2"... for debugging?

Comment: Remember `var1` and `var2` aren't variables and where used what `x[0]` or `x[1]` is may vary (or be undefined). 
As general rule simple aliasing `#define` are rarely helpful unless there's a good reason. It's often self defeating obfuscation.

Comment: Thx for the fast reply.
I know that using #defines in this sense is not really helpful, but i got this project with about 700 'defines'. Its easier to debug meaningful variablenames than just x[i+j*k].